# How to abort AJAX request until it returns any result

Tags: jquery, ajax

There is a functionality on my site which sends different ajax requests to the server. The duration of every request may be different (1 second - 3 minutes). There is a need to abort the request if it takes more then 30 seconds. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may set the timeout in your $.ajax method, as described in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

For example, following request would timeout in 1 min

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body,
    timeout: 60000,
    success: function(){
        $(this).addClass("done");
    },
    complete : function(xhr,status) {
        if(status == "timeout"){

        }
    }
});
```

You may write complete callback to check whether timeout happend

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = $.ajax(...);
setTimeout(function(){
    x.abort(); //cancel
}, 30000); // 30 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `timeout`

```
$.ajax({

timeout:30000,
//rest of params here
});
```

that works here http://jsfiddle.net/ZkgSB/

something else must be wrong

Answer (score 0):

There is one moment you have to pay your attention at. All realization are good and they work on **real servers**, but they will not work on **local server** (f.e. in Denwer or in other similar one).